# monitor ssl http request from non-browser

Tags: http, monitoring

Hi
I want to monitor SSL http request generated out of a exe. Is there any tool that can help me?

I trying fiddler but it cannt give information about header fields and etc.

Comment: Fiddler shows header fields under the "Session Inspector" tab. Have you tried that?

Answer (score 0):

You can try Charles : http://www.charlesproxy.com/
(you will have to accept the intermediate SSL certificat)

Answer (score 0):

Fiddler and Charles are proxy servers. So your exe must be configured to use proxy-server in order to monitor it.

If you don't want or can't change your exe settings, then you can use [HTTP Debugger](http://www.httpdebugger.com), which works on network level and monitors all in/out http traffic from your computer, including desktop applications and network services.